# File path error with proper path in openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

```
import openpyxl as op

from openpyxl import load_workbook

path = r'C:\Users\Name\Downloads\pandatest.xlsx'

wb = load_workbook(filename = path, read_only = True)
```

I get this error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:..`

Not sure what did I do wrong?

Comment: just to make sure things are working.  Place a copy of your workbook in the same folder as your Python script.  Then change your path to path = "pandatest.xlsx"   Once you can load the file, you can figure out if its the directory structure, the permissions, or something else.

Comment: @WombatPM I did that too, it does not work for some reason. I get the same error. But when I created an excel file it did actually save it to the directory

Comment: this is working in my PC, just check the path and file extension .xlsx or .xls or .xlsm